# Java SE VS. JDK and JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, windows, java-8, java-home

I know there are similar questions but I don't feel I really get the right answer anywhere. I want JDK and therefore download the zip file:

> jdk_ri-8u40-b25-windows-i586-10_feb_2015.zip

When I unzip the file I the folder is called

> java-se-8u40-ri

Now as I understand it the JDK is sort of included in Java SE? Why does the name change from jdk to java-se? My understanding is also that i should set the JDK folder as the JAVA_HOME variable, does that mean that in my case that I should set the path to the *java-se-8u40-ri* folder as the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: Where did you get that zip file from and why do you want to install a beta version of an ancient JDK version?